# Which ping implementation is Cygwin using?

Tags: cygwin, ping

What is the source of the implementation of ping is Cygwin using?

It apparently isn't GNU ping (because in GNU ping, the number of pings to send is decided with `-c X`, while in Cygwin ping, it's decided with `-n X`).

Is it a custom ping? [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) ping? [Toybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toybox) ping? NetBSD ping? OpenBSD ping? FreeBSD ping? Something else?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's Windows ping. Just run:

```
which ping
```

You'll get:

```
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ping
```

Comment: There's this github thread that confirms: https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/153

Comment: In case it's not clear to someone from reading this answer, this is the built-in `ping` command in Windows, not any sort of *nix `ping` command.

Answer (score 12):

Cygwin ping is available on ping package from inetutils source

```
$ which ping
/usr/bin/ping 

$ cygcheck -f `which ping`
ping-1.9.4-1

x86_64 $ ping --help
Usage: ping [OPTION...] HOST ...
Send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to network hosts.

 Options controlling ICMP request types:
      --address              send ICMP_ADDRESS packets (root only)
      --echo                 send ICMP_ECHO packets (default)
      --mask                 same as --address
      --timestamp            send ICMP_TIMESTAMP packets
  -t, --type=TYPE            send TYPE packets

 Options valid for all request types:

  -c, --count=NUMBER         stop after sending NUMBER packets
....
```

Comment: You should use `command -v ping`, not `which ping`. Also see [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639) and the discussion around Posix and environments.

Comment: And which ping implementation is that?

Comment: GNU https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/

Comment: @jww `command -v ping` and  `which ping` produces exactly the same output on my system as the ping package is installed. Eventually you can use  `which -a ping`

Comment: @matzeri the point is it won't on everyone else's system

Comment: @OrangeDog the question was about cygwin ping not windows ping. So you need the `ping` package installed if you want it.

Comment: Folks, there is also `where` command which shows all the available executables in the path:)

Comment: @saulius2 you are correct. `where ping` and `which -a ping` produce equivalent info from Windows and Cygwin reporting all the `ping` programs in the PATH